# D3: get element attribute inside selectAll

Tags: d3.js

```
<html>
    <svg></svg>
    <script src="d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            var svg = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("width", 1000)
                .attr("height", 500)
            ;
            for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            svg.append("rect")
                .attr("x",i*80)
                .attr("y",i*40)
                .attr("width",30)
                .attr("height",30)
            ;
            }
            svg.selectAll("rect")
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr("x",2*d3.select(this).attr("x"))
            ;
    </script>
</html>
```

The line with `d3.select(this).attr("x")` returns an error. So, which is the right code to read `x` attr of each element?

Comment: `.attr("x", function(){ return 2 * (+d3.select(this).attr("x"))})`. Just a curiosity: why are you using the semicolons like this?

Comment: I don't remember where I have seen it. Anyway, I do it to copy and paste from other code blocks without being obliged to check if there is the last line (which usually contains a semicolon). I hope I was clear. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Your comment made my day! The first part containing the answer makes it even funnier. Anyway, the coding style is not *that* unusual. Every once in a while I (or, my alter ego coding ABAP or SQL) stumble upon this pattern. See also: [*"Objective reasons against leading commas in Javascript \[closed\]"*](/q/18893948), https://hackernoon.com/winning-arguments-with-data-leading-with-commas-in-sql-672b3b81eac9 .

Comment: @tlc you can omit semicolons in Javascript, which would make your life even easier!

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `attr` function of `d3` takes either a value, or a function. In your example you're passing it a constant value (which is supposed to be the body of a function).

Therefore the `d3.select(this)` is going to operate on whatever `this` is in scope, most likely the `global` object. Instead wrap this in a function like so:

```
.attr("x", function() { 2 * d3.select(this).attr("x"); })
```

Alternatively you could use the following approach (version dependant)

```
.attr("x", (d, i, elements) => 2 * d3.select(elements[i]).attr("x"));
```

**Note** that currently you're also not applying any protection on the `x` value, I would seriously consider throwing it through a `parseFloat()` before trying to do any arithmetic on it.